# Where should I instantiate confidental client application?

Tags: .net, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

In [this guide on implementing Azure AD auth in a deamon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-app-configuration?tabs=dotnet#instantiate-the-confidential-client-application-with-a-client-secret) app, the guide tells you to "instantiate the confidential client application".
But it does not say where you should instantiate it.

Can I simply instantiate it to a field in the class where I need to use it?
Should it be instantiated somewhere else? Maybe in Startup.cs?

It just seem "too good to be true" that you simply instantiate it when you need it, and I don't want to have a potential performance hit, or other complications, and this seems suspicious to me.

[image]

Comment: Is my answer useful to this question? If this answer is not correct, please let me know so we can investigate this issue together.

Comment: I have not had time to work on the project. I will let you know when I have had so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should can MSALAuthProvider class which contain the code like the link you provided.

```
public class MSALAuthProvider : IAuthProvider
{
}
```

Then Register it in Startup.cs or Program.cs file

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthProvider, MSALAuthProvider>();
```

**Related Link**

[MSALAuthProvider](https://github.com/anoopt/Azure-application-to-application-authentication/blob/main/Client/Helpers/MSALAuth.cs#L26)

Comment: Looking at the code in the link, and your answer, this makes perfect sense. I would just like to add, to those who don't dig into the code in the link, that the `IAuthProvider` is just a custom interface, not part of a package.